# Excel - RGB HSL keeps "Autocorrecting" and changing values

Tags: excel, colors

So I know basically nothing about colors apart from the very basics.

I have a color I'm trying to mimic.

I copied it, stuck it in paint, and used the color feature to get the RGB HSL numbers. Great!

RGB: 0; 49; 70
HSL: 132; 240; 33

The issue: When I try to manually input them into Excel, it "autocorrects" the RGB values after I enter in the HSL, and it "autocorrects" the HSL when I re-enter the RGB.

Why is this happening? Is this just an aspect to colors I know nothing about? Some limitation on Excel?

For reference, when I put in just the RGB, I'm much closer (but not quite there) on the color I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HSL** and **RGB** are two ways of "translating colors" into numbers.

**HSL** means **Hue**, **Saturation**, **Lightness**.

- Hue is a degree on the color wheel from 0 to 360. 0 is red, 120 is green, 240 is blue.
- Saturation is a percentage value; 0% means a shade of gray and 100% is the full color.
- Lightness is also a percentage; 0% is black, 100% is white.

**RGB** means **Red**, **Green**, **Blue**, each of which is given a value between 0 and 255 in Excel.

---

Check this tool -  https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp

If you put 0, 49, 70 for **HSL** you would see that it gets translated to 216, 141, 141 into **RGB**.

Excel is following the same logic, thus once you adjust the **RGB** the **HSL** gets automatically adjusted to represent the same color.

Comment: @pnuts - if you are referencing to a question from yesterday, at least the OP has made some research here.

Comment: @Vityata: Thank you! Do you have any speculation why the paint "color identifier" gives two sets of numbers that end up being different colors then?

Comment: @Selkie - You are welcome. Concerning the paint - if the values are different then I am just guessing it is because "MS Paint" is quite an old program and it uses old values, when the colors of Windows were not 256^3, but quite less. Thus, it is not updated due to some compatibility issues. But these are just guesses.

Answer (score 1):

### Excel colors are confusing because they don't follow the standard

Although the first reason you may have been confused was if you didn't know that RGB and HSL are two different ways of describing colors (and that every RGB color code has an equivalent HSL color code—see examples below), **a second reason many people can get confused when selecting colors in Excel particularly is:**

> “Frustratingly, Excel does not handle HSL in the standard way.  Instead, Excel measures all the numbers where 0 is the lowest and 255 is the biggest.  But, it’s a quirk we can handle.” - https://exceloffthegrid.com/convert-color-codes/

> “This approach assumes that each of your HSL values can be express in the range of 0 to 255. If, however, your HSL values are either an angle (for hue) or a percentage (for saturation and luminance), then you'll need to convert them manually before entering them in step 6. You can convert an angle value by multiplying the angle by 255 and then dividing by 360. Percentages can be converted by multiplying them by 2.55.” - https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013535_Converting_HSL_to_RGB.html

> “To change the lightness (adding white) or darkness (adding black), drag your selection up and down the luminance scale on the right. Notice that the Lum value increases as the color gets lighter. Full luminance is 255 (white), and setting Lum to 0 results in black regardless of the hue and saturation settings.” - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choosing-colors-in-the-colors-dialog-box-c3d59ddf-65a7-4e62-aad7-f7b8d7684a2d

### Examples of converting RGB color codes to HSL

rgb(0, 49, 70) = hsl(198, 100%, 14%)

[image: Google color picker for]

These independent sites agree with Google that that RGB code converts to that HSL code:

- https://colorpicker.me/#003146
- https://hslpicker.com/#003146

**So if someone told you that rgb(0, 49, 70) was equivalent to hsl(132, 240, 33), they were mistaken (even when using Excel's non-standard way of calculating HSL).**